# Django view error 'bool' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the follwing error message the I try to open the url:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/core/jmc/material/generate
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 21
```

Also the traceback looks like this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/Documents/Program Codes/Python/Django/Zeus2/core/project/jmc.py" in jmc_material_generator
168.         jmc_material_generator(False)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
21.             if test_func(request.user):
```

My view is as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def jmc_material_generator(request):
    # Permission level check
    if request.user.groups.all()[0].name not in ['Super-Admin', 'Admin']:
        return redirect('index')

    with transaction.atomic():
        jmc_material_generator(False)
return redirect('index')
```

Comment: From your trackback, it seems that you somehow passed `False` to the `jmc_material_generator` in jmc.py, which explains the exception: 'bool' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: Removing 'False' from the argument, I am getting "_wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)".

Comment: You're supposed to pass django's `HttpRequest` to `jmc_material_generator`, which you'll normally get when user visits the url that routes to the `jmc_material_generator` view

Comment: It seems to work just fine if I comment out 'jmc_material_generator(False)'. I think this function is some how interfering with login_required decorator, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I actually made a stupid mistake, I just named the view and the function the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your view function name is the same as the function being called on line 8 (`jmc_material_generator(False)`). This in turn is calling your view function again and passing in a boolean instead of a request object. You need to either rename your view function or rename the `jmc_material_generator(False)` import when you import it into the `view.py` file.

```
# you can do import x as X which renamed the imported function
from ... import jmc_material_generator as jmc_generator

@login_required(login_url='login')
def jmc_material_generator(request):
    # Permission level check
    if request.user.groups.all()[0].name not in ['Super-Admin', 'Admin']:
        return redirect('index')

    with transaction.atomic():
        jmc_generator(False) # notice the rename of this function
return redirect('index')
```